# Understanding Common Lisp aref behavior

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I don't understand why `setf` will not work with an array reference returned from a function call.  In the below example, why does the final call fail?

```
(setf arr #1a(a b c))

(defun ret-aref (a i)
    (aref a i))

(eql (ret-aref arr 0) (aref arr 0))

;succeeds
(progn
    (setf (aref arr 0) 'foo)
    arr)

;fails
(progn
    (setf (ret-aref arr 0) 'bar)
    arr)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `setf` operator is actually a macro, which needs to be able to inspect the place-form already at compile time. It has special knowledge about `aref`, but doesn't know anything about your `ret-aref`.

The easiest way to make your function known to `setf` is by defining a suitable `setf`-function companion for it. Example:

```
(defun (setf ret-aref) (new-value array index) 
   (setf (aref array index) new-value))
```

Now, `(setf (ret-aref arr 0) 'bar)` should work.

This simple example hides the fact, that `setf`-expansion is actually a pretty hairy topic. You can find the gory details [in the CLHS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/05_aab.htm).